# How to save state when using strategy pattern

Tags: java, strategy-pattern

I'm am trying to implement a feed using the strategy pattern.
I have a few different types of ways in which feeds item are retrieved, e.g. all, suggested, by a search.

```
public interface IGetFeedItemsStrategy{
    FeedItems getFeedItems(int start, int amount);
}
```

The implementations looks like this:

```
public Class GetSuggestedFeedItemsStrategy implements IGetFeedItemsStrategy{
     private FeedDao feedDao;

     public GetSearchedFeedItemsStrategy(FeedDao feedDao
         this.feedDao = feedDao;
     }

     FeedItems getFeedItems(int start, int amount){
         return feedDao.getSuggestedItems(start, amount);
     }
}




public Class GetSearchedFeedItemsStrategy implements IGetFeedItemsStrategy{
     private FeedModel feedModel;
     private FeedDao feedDao;

     public GetSearchedFeedItemsStrategy(FeedDao feedDao, FeedModel feedModel){
         this.feedDao = feedDao;
         this.feedModel = feedModel;
     }


     FeedItems getFeedItems(int start, int amount){
         return feedDao.getSearchedItems(start, amount, feedModel.getSearchPhrase());
     }
}
```

When a user clicks a button to change what type of results they want the controller calls `setGetFeedItemsStategy(new GetSuggestedFeedItemsStrategy)` or whatever. Now whenever the controller has to refresh the feed or paginate through result it uses whatever strategy has been set.

My question is whether it is okay to save references to other 'entity' and 'service' objects in strategy class implementations? Here the `feedDao` was injected into the controller and the `feedModel` was created by `feedModel = new FeedModel()` in the constructor. I'm confused because I've read that entities and services should be kept seperate. e.g. (http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/03/04/How-not-to-inject-services-in-entities). I'm wondering whether a strategy object is either?

Comment: The way you have phrased this question it might be put on hold or closed.

Comment: @LukeMelaia I presume you cast the 'too broad' close vote. Care to say why? I'm literally asking a yes or no question. How is that too broad?

Comment: I did not flag this question nor do I intend to. Im simply stating that your asking for a good design pattern (or similar) and that will generate too many answer. Perhaps simplify your question at the last paragraph so that it is easier to read, sum up all the questions.

Comment: @LukeMelaia I'm not asking for a good design pattern. It's obvious from the question that the strategy pattern is what I am trying to use. My question is whether it is ok to save the model in a strategy implementation for later use.

Comment: I apologise for that. I suppose I miss read it.

Comment: Although could you please prove a bit more detail? Im getting somewhat confused with what all the classes are, how its all fitting together, ect. At the very least, would it be possible to provide the code for the `FeedModel` and `FeedDao` class?

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing why you need this layer of abstraction? You are passing a `FeedModel` into the constructor of the strategy and passing a `FeedDao` into a method of this "`FeedModel` wrapper class" and you return the results of a method on the `FeedDao` you passed in.

Comment: @cricket_007 I want this layer of abstraction because the user can refresh the feed, scroll to the bottom and more feed items appear. So every time something like this happens feed items need to be retrieved from the internet or wherever. I could have used an Enum describing what type of result the user is currently viewing for example but I am trying to use the strategy pattern.

Comment: @cricket_007 I agree, it's seems silly to pass the FeedModel into the constructor and feedDao into a method. I'll change that.

Comment: Alright, looking better. Is Dao referring to a Data Access Object? If so, what is the difference between `FeedModel` and `FeedDao`? Can you updated your question with those classes?

Comment: @cricket_007  I updated it again. I think your comment almost answered my question.